# setting Next-Auth custom cookies

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cookies, oauth, next-auth

I want to set two custom cookies in next-auth named 'email' and 'accessToekn'. I can't seem to do it. It seems next-auth is removing my cookies and setting its own four default. How can I set these two cookies? These are my files:

This is authOptions.ts file where I try to set the cookies:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import KeycloakProvider from 'next-auth/providers/keycloak';
export const authOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  cookies: {
    email: {
      name: 'email',
      options: {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'lax',
        path: '/',
        secure: true,
      },
    },
    accessToken: {
      name: 'accessToken',
      options: {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'lax',
        path: '/',
        secure: true,
      },
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  providers: [
    KeycloakProvider({
      clientId: process.env.KEYCLOAK_ID || '',
      clientSecret: process.env.KEYCLOAK_SECRET || '',
      issuer: process.env.NEXTAUTH_CLIENT_ISSUER,
      //@ts-ignore
      profile: (profile) => {
        return {
          ...profile,
          id: profile?.sub,
          firstName: profile?.given_name,
          lastName: profile?.family_name,
          mobileNumber: profile?.mobileNumber,
          phoneNumber: profile?.phoneNumber,
          companyName: profile?.companyName,
          companyPhoneNumber: profile?.companyPhoneNumber,
          companyAddress: profile?.companyAddress,
        };
      },
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account, user }: any) {
      // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
        token.refreshToken = account.refresh_token;
        token.provider = account.provider;
        token.exp = account.expires_at;
        token.user = account.user;
        token.idToken = account.id_token;
        token.user = user;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }: any) {
      // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider.
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      session.refreshToken = token.refreshToken;
      session.user = token.user;

      // Set custom cookies
      if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
        const { res } = session;
        if (res) {
          // Set email cookie
          res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', `email=${token.user.email}; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure`);
          // Set accessToken cookie
          res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', `accessToken=${token.accessToken}; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure`);
        }
      }

      return session;
    },
  },
  events: {
    signOut: async ({ token }: any) => {
      // Kill the session on keycloak server on behalf of user
      if (token.provider === 'keycloak') {
        await axios.get(
          `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_CLIENT_ISSUER}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?id_token_hint=${token.idToken}`,
        );
      }
    },
  },
};
```

and this is my api/auth/[...nextauth] file:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { authOptions } from './authOptions';

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

also this is a middleware I'm using for the project:

```
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - api (API routes)
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     */
    "/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|images|favicon.ico).*)",
  ],
};
export default withAuth({
  // Matches the pages config in `[...nextauth]`
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
});
```

Also, I try to use these cookies inside of axios.ts file that you see in my file tree. But I can't even get the cookies that next auth sets by default. it returns undefined.

[image][image]

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { getCookie } from '@/utils/cookie';
import errorHandling from '@/services/errorHandling';

export const baseURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_BASE_URL;

const headers: { [key: string]: any } = {};

const axiosApiInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL,
  headers,
});

axiosApiInstance.interceptors.request.use((req: any) => {
  console.log('cook', getCookie('next-auth.session-token.0'), getCookie('email'));
  if (!process.browser && req.headers.common.accessToken) {
    req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${req.headers.common.accessToken}`;
  } else if (getCookie('next-auth.session-token.0')) {
    req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${getCookie('next-auth.session-token.0')}`;
  }
  return req;
});
```